# Razor syntax error in my View

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm new to mvc and Razor and need your help

Can anyone see why my 2 line Razor code getting error in my view.

```
    <div class=@( if(true){ "divred" } )> Iam in if the block</div>
```

Iam in if the block

        Iam in if the block 4


Here is my entire code

    @{
        string divClass = "enable";
        string blue = "divred";
    }




    

    
    
        
        Index

        
            .divred{color:red;}
            .divblue{color:blue;}
        
    
    
         


             Iam in if the block

     Iam in if the block

```
        <div @(divClass == "enable" ? "class=@blue" : "class=divblue" )>Iam in if the block 4</div>


    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I will be glad if someone can explain in detail. As I said I am brand new to mvc

Comment: And what is the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass a C# expression which ultimately return the string value based on your if condition inside the `@()` code block.

This should work.

```
<div class='@(true?Html.Raw("divred"):Html.Raw("divblue"))'> Iam in if the block</div>
```

Here `Html.Raw("divred")` returns the string "divred" as it is (no encoding)

You can replace the `true` in the expression with any C# statement which returns a boolean value.